# ADF error " Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'mappingV2'" while mapping a @pipeline().parameters.myParameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

While retrieving API response from an API using CopyData in ADF. I would like to map `@pipeline().parameters.myParameter` so that it can get sinked with the data in the same row but a different Table.

When I go to dynamic mapping to select the `@pipeline().parameters.myParameter`, all other mappings get removed and I get an error "`Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'mappingV2'`"

Now, my data type on the mapping also shows String. but I am not sure how to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

- The mapping has to be a map object but not string. When I gave a string value to parameter `map` (value 'hello'), I get a similar warning.

[image]

- Let's say I have the following as my source:

[image]

- Using the following parameter (**object type**) value, I was able to give a dynamic mapping to get only `id and first_name`

```
{
   "type":"TabularTranslator",
   "mappings":[
      {
         "source":{
            "name":"id"
         },
         "sink":{
            "name":"id"
         }
      },
      {
         "source":{
            "name":"first_name"
         },
         "sink":{
            "name":"firstName"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

- The result of the copy activity would be as shown in the below image (only id and firstname are mapped).

[image]